# SearchView in Toolbar only in "search mode"

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I have MainActivity and SearchAcitivty. When I click "Szukaj" ("Search") I open SearchAcitivty:

[image: MainActivity]

When I open SearchActivity, it shows a list with the option of clicking the magnifying glass to search views in list view.

[image: SearchActivity - list]

I would like to start activity **immediately in "search mode" (as clicked magnifying glass)** or, what's more important, **don't back to list when the user clicks back button, but to MainActivity** (Facebook has this functionality)

[image: Search mode]

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener` to my MenuItem to finish activity when SearchView is collapsed and call method `menuItem.expandActionView()` to expand SearchView on start activity:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
    val menuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.searchIcon)
    menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(this)
    menuItem.expandActionView()
    return true
}

override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    finish()
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
    return true
}
```

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

programmatically, you can register a click on the magnifying glass and for going back to the main activity, set is as the default activity in the manifest and then use this in your search activity

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but that's not the solution